# Taken From The New And Black

Tags: riddle

> Taken from the new and black,
>   Stripped of all its limbs.
>   Draped over by a canvas sack,
>   Blasted by a salty wind.

What is being described by the above passage?
Please add reasoning for each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility is a

> tree.

Taken from the new and black

> This may refer to the famous New Forest and Black Forest

Stripped of all its limbs.

> The branches are now removed.

Draped over by a canvas sack,

> The tree is now made into the mast of a ship with a canvas sail.

blasted by a salty wind.

> The sea sprayed winds are salty.

Comment: Excellent, well done! I had thought of the answer being the end product rather than the start but both work :)